# Adjusting the title

Tags: r, shiny

Is there a R function to adjust the title " Factors under the dataset " and "Numbers under the dataset". Below is the code I have tried. So I need the title at the middle of the grey coloured bar

```
  library(shiny)

  ui <- fluidPage(
  tabsetPanel(tabPanel(
  "Factor_Univariate_Analysis",sidebarLayout(
  sidebarPanel(
    column(h6(selectInput("se1","Factors under the dataset",choices = 
  c("","Add","sub"))),width = 11,height= 20,offset = 0),width = 1000),
  mainPanel(h5(plotOutput("Plot1",width = 1000,height = 1500)))
  )
  ),
  tabPanel(
  "Numeric_Univariate_Analysis",sidebarLayout(
   sidebarPanel(
    column(h6(selectInput("se2","Numbers under the dataset",choices = 
   c("","mean","median","standard_deviation","Data Distribution"))),width 
  = 11,height= 20,offset = 0),width = 1000),
  mainPanel(h5(plotOutput("Plot2",width = 1500,height = 500)))
  )
  )
  )
  )

   server <- function(input, output, session) {

   }

   shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: You are ill-adviced to use the `sidebarLayout` *inside* tabPanels. Unless you start fiddling a lot with CSS, `sidebarLayout` with `sidebarPanel` and `mainPanel` should be used as the outer framework for building the page.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code which I think is close to what you want to do, I'll just explain a few things first:

I have five years experience as a web developer, so I enjoy using CSS, and I would recommend using it where ever possible. What I beleive you were trying to do is give the label a background, this can be done with CSS. In this case I have put it in the style and html tags. label {} applies styles to all `label`s. You might want to agust the `background` color.

I have removed the side panel layouts.

Hopefully you find this helpful.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$style(HTML("

      label {
        width: 100%;
        background: lightgrey;
        padding: 5px;
        border-radius: 5px;
      }



    ")),

  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel(
      "Factor_Univariate_Analysis",
      div(
        column(width = 12,
          h6(
            selectInput(
              "se1",
              label = "Factors under the dataset",
              choices = c("","Add","sub"),
              width = "100%"
            )
          )
        ),
        div(plotOutput("Plot1",width = 1000,height = 1500))
      )
  ),
  tabPanel(
    "Numeric_Univariate_Analysis",
        column(width = 12,
          h6(
            selectInput(
              "se2",
              "Numbers under the dataset",
              choices = c("","mean","median","standard_deviation","Data Distribution"),
              width = "100%"
            )
          )
        ),
      div(plotOutput("Plot2",width = 1500,height = 500))

  )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observe({
    print(input$se1)
    updateSelectInput(session, input$se1, label = "Factors under the dataset replaced")
  })

}
# https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/updateSelectInput.html
shinyApp(ui, server)
```